# Select values which are not in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have two tables.

```
Table client

ID - primary key ( 1,2,3,4,5,6)




Table Orders

OrderID - primary key

ClientID (1,2,4,5)
```

I need to get ROWS of table CLIENT of clients 3 and 6 (which don't have orders / are not in orders table)

Comment: Okay but what have you tried so far? Can you should your basic SQL code?

Comment: not in () is bad with nullability in table2, but you can do a left join with nulls on right table. Most of my comments are cryptic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic query. Try your self.

```
select * from client where id not in (select ClientID from orders)
```